# How do you say numbers/letters in a skipped sequence or connected by a dash?

Tags: pronunciation

I keep running into things like 1-3 or a-d in my workbook but i can't figure out how to read them aloud. Is it 1から3 sort of like in english? is it a literal aダッシュd? something completely different? A google search only gives me straight up numbers or tells me the dash is for elongating vowels. For the sake of my internal monologue, please, I'm dyingggg

Comment: Hello Welcome to the Site. Can you clarify what you are wondering about more specific? I think it depends. Do you struggling with how to read address: 4-12-2 or class room number: 3-5?I think you mean「1から3」should be expressed in a line as (1 ≤ x ≤ 3) in most case.

Comment: @kimiTanaka I think the OP means things like "examples a-d above are not grammatical" in a text book, for example. i.e there are four sentences marked a), b), c) and d).

Comment: @user3856370 Thank you for clarification! I think I do not read the symbol "-" in multiple choice quiz. I think most people put focus on what you need to do/solve in the quiz/exam. i.e. **choose one** of  "1-3" or "a-d" : 「1-3のうち**どれか一つを選べ**" 」or  「"a-dのうち**どれか一つを選べ**"」. The bold part is important in the task. But I think reading "-" as 「から」 is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep running into things like 1-3 or a-d in my workbook but i can't figure out how to read them aloud. Is it 1から3 sort of like in english?

Yes, いちからさん or エーからディー　(or デー).

> is it a literal aダッシュd?

The - as part of a word is often called ハイフン in Japan, ダッシュ usually means to hurry.

> A google search only gives me straight up numbers or tells me the dash is for elongating vowels.

The "long dash" called ちょうおん is used for elongating vowels as in the word for "paper", ペーパー. You won't see Japanese people writing ペ-パ- for "paper" using a short hyphen.